# I have a question in sql to replace a manually entered number to a query to find total number of distinct states

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
select
  concat(ceiling((count(prac.state)*100)/31),'%') as Percentage
from(
    select
      us.state,
      round(sum (case when month(ord.order_date) <=6 and year(ord.order_date) = '2022' then prod.amount * ord.quantity else 0 end), 1) as rev_H1_22, 
      round(sum (case when month(ord.order_date) <=6 and year(ord.order_date) = '2023' then prod.amount * ord.quantity else 0 end), 1) as rev_H1_23
    from ((dbo.users as us
    join dbo.orders as ord on us.id = ord.user_id)
    join dbo.prods as prod on ord.product_id = prod.prod_id)
    group by us.state
) as Prac
where prac.rev_H1_22 > prac.rev_H1_23
```

I want to replace the 31 in the concat function in line no.1 with count of total number of distinct states , what should I do, the prac is the count of the distinct states that have h12022>h12023.

replacing 31 with count of total number of distinct states

Comment: Change count(prac.state) to count(case when prac.rev_H1_22 > prac.rev_H1_23 then prac.state end ) and 31 to COUNT(*), 100 to 100.0 and remove the WHERE

Comment: Which product are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: sql server, ssms

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned by @siggemannen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76678460/i-have-a-question-in-sql-to-replace-a-manually-entered-number-to-a-query-to-find/76678577?noredirect=1#comment135187443_76678460), remove the `WHERE` and put it into the `COUNT`, then change `31` to `COUNT(*)`

```sql
select
  concat(
    ceiling(count(case when prac.rev_H1_22 > prac.rev_H1_23 then 1 end) * 100.0) 
      / count(*),
    '%') as Percentage
from(
    select
      us.state,
      round(sum (case when month(ord.order_date) <=6 and year(ord.order_date) = 2022 then prod.amount * ord.quantity else 0 end), 1) as rev_H1_22, 
      round(sum (case when month(ord.order_date) <=6 and year(ord.order_date) = 2023 then prod.amount * ord.quantity else 0 end), 1) as rev_H1_23
    from dbo.users as us
    join dbo.orders as ord on us.id = ord.user_id
    join dbo.prods as prod on ord.product_id = prod.prod_id
    group by us.state
) as Prac;
```

Comment: thanks a lot, for this, was struggling on this.